# Use from two xupload exntention in one file

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii-xupload

I want two user from two exuploded file in one form in yii..how can do this?

```
 $this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
        'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload"),
        'model' => $photos,
        'showForm'=>true,
        'htmlOptions' => array('id'=>'place-form','name'=>'album'),
        //'options'=>array('style'=>"border:solid thin red;"),
        //'formView'=>"CActiveForm",
        'attribute' => 'file',
        //'formView' => 'application.views.XUpload.form',
        'uploadTemplate' => '#template-upload',
        //'autoUpload'=>false,
        'multiple' => true,

    ));
```